# Parsing Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to put together a program that wil parse through mongodb and get each page (eventually I will want to graph it) but I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  I have been through the tutorial http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html
but it I don't know how to query dynamically (looping through). My guess is that it has something to do with results being returned in unicode but i'm not sure.  Here is my code.

```
import pymonogo
from pymongo import Connection
c = Connection()
dbs = c.database_names()
for db in dbs:
  print db
  for col in c[db].collection_names():
    print '\t', col
    for pag in c[db].col.find():
      print pag
```

I'm just doing some analytics on an existing databases. (I have about 5 dbs that each have 1-20 collections, each collection has from 0 - 1500 pages. I am hoping to graph the pages, but I haven't gotten far enough into the graphing library yet to see exactly how that will work out.

If you can help thanks.

Comment: It's not completely clear what are you trying to achieve. In what database and collection do your pages live?

Comment: I edited it with more detail, hopefully that is clear enough, if not let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get all of the data from all dbs and all collections, then your code was almost right. Here's the code with a small fix (`c[db][col]` instead of `c[db].col`):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

c = MongoClient()
dbs = c.database_names()
for db in dbs:
    print db
    for col in c[db].collection_names():
        print '\t', col
        for pag in c[db][col].find():
            print pag
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I needed.  Thanks,  Are those pages returned as dictionaries?

Comment: Great answer, I'm going to update it as Connection() has been deprecated by MongoDB.